# Is it possible to customize slider in qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to make a slider with an image? not as a background but like an image i pull up and down instead of the slider?

I have searched around and saw some examples of redrawing a slider, is it something like this i need to do, if so any examples you can link me too?

Also saw something called QML slider, can my project be achieved with that, if so any examples would be great!

I should mention im new to Qt and programming in general, so sorry in advance for any stupid mistakes i migth make .

Comment: This site is not to recommend tutorials ;)

Comment: @Theolodis Doesn't need to link to an example, just want to know if it is possible really, and how i can achieve it if it is possible :)

Comment: Have you tried using a QStyleSheet on the slider handle? http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qscrollbar? But then with an image as either the background or border-image.

Comment: In a question like this, you should really show some code to give context. Otherwise the question is too vague, because the short answer is "yes, it is possible in several different ways".

Comment: @hyde I can see the title question can be a bit to vague, but I do not think the questions in my post would be any better suplied with code. I could have tried some code out first only then to find out it didn't work. Instead I ask a few vague question that is gonna save me alot of time, because I will get precise ways i can handle my problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the [Slider](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-slider.html) from Qt Quick Controls:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.1

Item {
    width: 400
    height: 400
    Slider {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        style: SliderStyle {
            handle: Image {
                source: "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/pretty-office-9/256/square-icon.png"
                width: 14
                height: 14
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: custom-slider-handle]

See [SliderStyle's documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-sliderstyle.html) for more information.

Comment: as much as i hate qtquick/qml, i have to admit that this is incredibly simple.

Comment: Okay i looked up the documentation and found out i needed to make a QML file with the above code. My stupid question is then, how do I use it? I have tried just creating a slider normally but that looks the same? How do I actually use this in my mainwindow?

Comment: Oh, you need to [create a Qt Quick application in Qt Creator](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-3.0/creator-qml-application.html). After you've done that, you can copy this code into the `main.qml` file that is created for you.

Also, you'll need Qt 5.1 or newer to use these controls. I suggest just downloading the latest Qt SDK if you don't have Qt 5.1.

Comment: Oh thanks, I have followed the first few steps of that link. My window is still empty though, and when I go to the designer there is a slider but I can't seem to "add" it or show it when i run? [Picture of how qt designer looks](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11985086/Wierd.png)

Comment: This answer fails to explain how to hook that up to the rest of the application... Of course the question also fails to give enough details to make this possible.

Comment: That's odd... it says it can't find those modules, but they have been available since Qt 5.2. Can you put your .pro file contents on pastebin/some paste site?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/gG56Yqmf

Comment: @hyde This is a self-contained example; how to create a Qt Quick application is an entirely different question in itself, to be fair. Sumsar1812, I've updated my answer, but I'm not sure why you're getting the error.

Comment: one quick follow up question, Can I make it vertical ? thanks again
Nvm found out how `orientation: Qt.Vertical`

Answer (score 2):

In Qt, you can customize almost all of the UI with stylesheets. For the documentation and a quick tutorial, you might want to take a look to [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html) and [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html).

I haven't tested this, but it might work(please note that you will have to adde the handle to the qrc):

`setStyleSheet("QSlider::handle:horizontal{background-image:url(:/images/fancySliderHandle.png);}");`

You might also want to check [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html) for documentation(under `QSlider`). A syntax guide (in case you will be having trouble with my approach) can be found [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html).

Comment: I have now tried your solution too but doesn't seem to work
And yes I have changed the "handle" : `slider->setStyleSheet("QSlider::handle:horizontal{background-image:url(:/new/prefix1/draft.png);}");`
It only shows the normal slider

Comment: Have you added the image to your qrc file? If not,that is the problem. for a quick info on qrc: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/resources.html